# Why does my function work without a return statement (JS)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, frontend, return

I'm learning javascript; I'm confused about when to use 'return.' So far I know 'return' is used either to specify exactly what value to return or to stop a function from running.

But, when comparing my solution to the answer key, its function required a return statement, but mine did not. Yet, both displayed the same results on the console. Why? Are the results actually different?

***Problem**:
"Using a WHILE loop, calculate the percentage of students' test scores stored in the testScore array. The test has a total of 50. Store the percentages in another array and display it to the console."*

**My Solution:**

```
const testScore = [10, 40, 30, 25];
const percentages = [];

const gradePercentage = (scores) => {
  const perc = (scores / 50) * 100;
  percentages.push(perc);
};

let i = 0;
while (i < testScore.length) {
  gradePercentage(testScore[i]);
  i++;
}
console.log(percentages);
```

**Answer Key**

```
const testScore = [10, 40, 30, 25];
const percentages = [];

const gradePercentage = (scores) => {
  return (scores / 50) * 100;
};

let i = 0;
while (i < testScore.length) {
  const perc = gradePercentage(testScore[i]);
  percentages.push(perc); 
  i++;
}
console.log(percentages);
```

**Both displayed this result:**

[image]

Comment: The *implicit return value* of your arrow function is the result of evaluating the last statement. `Array#push` returns the result of pushing the item, so the value you're seeing matches returning the array explicitly.

Comment: More: [Returning a value without an explicit return statement](/questions/16895683/returning-a-value-without-an-explicit-return-statement), [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions), [Does every Javascript function have to return a value?](/questions/17337064/does-every-javascript-function-have-to-return-a-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run your function, you directly mutate `percentages` by calling `percentages.push(perc);`, while the answer key's `gradePercentage` function does not mutate `percentages`.

The answer key does what is called [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), a deterministic function which has no side effects. Personally, I prefer to write this sort of functions, since they can be easily tested.